# Windows Task Scheduler - specify time window, but only fire once

Tags: windows, backup

I want to run a backup twice a day, but I'm unable to make assumptions on when the computer is turned on. As an example: If I create a task in the task scheduler to run a backup script at 9 AM and 9 PM, I have no guarantee that the backup will run, since the computer might be powered on at 10 AM and shutdown at 8 PM.

Is there an easy way to specify a time window in which a backup should take place within the windows task scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

The easiest way to handle it is to tell the users to never shut it down.  Admittedly that's not terribly useful depending on your environment.

You can scheduled a job to run on startup or on logon.  That would theoretically catch your 9 AM window.

The hard one would be the 9PM backup.  You may be able to use the "Wake the computer to run this task" option on the Conditions tab depending on your power settings.  You could, theoreticlaly, use GPEdit.MSC to set a shutdown script to run the backup when the system is shutdown.  But that has it's own special set of issues depending on if the backup location is local or remote.  Additionally this method has the potential of users thinking the shutdown is taking too long and killing power.